# Why do visuals which get data from Power BI dataset break in a composite report after publishing to Power BI service?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, data-modeling

In Power BI desktop I have a report in import mode. This has a gateway connection mapping configured and it refreshes automatically every three hours by fetching data from an [SQL Server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server) database.

I create a new report and connect it to the above Power BI dataset (live dataset mode). Then I add a new data source - Excel workbook. This converts the report into composite model. I add visuals using data from live dataset (that is now a [DirectQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-directquery-about) (DQ), because this is a composite model) and Excel workbook (that is import mode).

After publishing this report to the Power BI workspace, when I open the report, **the visuals pointing to the live (technically DQ) dataset break**. Error: Can't display the visual. I couldn't retrieve the data for this visual.

> Error: There is no gateway to access the data source File.

In this report's dataset's setting page if I expand Gateway and cloud connections then it won't allow me to choose any gateway mapping. Under cloud connections section I can see the URL of the live (now DQ) dataset but I can't choose a mapping, neither can I create a new connection/mapping.

If a create a connection (via gateway) for the excel file then I'm able to map the Excel file fine, but there isn't any way to map the live dataset.

Is deploying of a composite model unsupported?

Interestingly, if I use a SharePoint based Excel file rather than an [on-premises](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On-premises_software) Excel file, and deploy the report, then Power BI automatically created the web (to the SharePoint file) and dataset (to live dataset) gateway connection mappings.

However, my goal is to use an on-premises Excel file and not a SharePoint based Excel file. What can I do to fix it?

Comment: Do you have any calculated columns or calculated tables that reference the DQ dataset?

Comment: Yes there is one calculated table in the live (now DQ model) but I'm not using that table in this new report.

Comment: Ok I tried to do the same but this time without a calculated table in the DQ dataset. Still facing the same issue. Are you able to reproduce this?

Comment: Yes.  Looks like you can't configure the DQ connection without also configuring a connection to the Excel file.

Comment: But if you see the error suggests something to do with the live (now DQ) dataset. Also visuals referring to that dataset break. The visuals from the excel data source work just fine. In this report's dataset's setting page if I expand Gateway and cloud connections then it won't allow me to choose any gateway. But under cloud connections I can see the url of the live (now DQ) dataset but I can't choose a mapping, neither can I create a new one. So this is something to do with the live (now DQ) dataset connection issue or a product bug?

Comment: You need a gateway connection for the Excel file connection.

Comment: I haven't tried your solution as I don't have permission to add gateway data sources. However my observation so far has been: 1. The table from excel datasource is in import mode; 2. The visual from the excel datasource works fine. Are you able to reproduce the solution?

Comment: Yes.  You must configure _both_ connections.  So you need a gateway connection for the Excel file.  Alternatively you could use an Excel file in OneDrive, which wouldn't require a gateway.

Comment: Excel for onedrive works fine. Thanks. But I must work with an on-prem excel file. When I publish the file (with an on-prem excel file + live dataset as described in my question), even if I add a gateway connection (and map the excel file), I'm still unable to map the PBI dataset. Have you tried this? Basically the problem is that I'm not able to map the dataset.

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding of the scenario is pretty accurate. As people here explained in the comments, a composite model enables you to build complex models from multiple DirectQuery datasets and/or Import. However, when mixing with on-prem sources, there are complications because of the Gateway.

Power BI datasets (which use DQ) in a composite model do NOT use the on-premises data gateway since they use a direct cloud-to-cloud connection.

Imported data, such as your on-premises Excel file, require an on-premises data gateway.

When you mix these two, you end up in a scenario where one part of the model requires a gateway and the other doesn't. This is where you're running into problems.

One workaround is to continue using your existing dataset (from SQL Server) without any additional imported data. For the Excel data, create a new dataset that's solely based on importing that Excel file through the on-premises gateway. Then, in your report, you can use both datasets as needed. However, this would mean you can't create relationships between the two datasets in a single report.

Or you can use Dataflows to ingest your Excel data into a storage option in the cloud (Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2). Once your Excel data is in the cloud through Dataflows, you can combine it with your DirectQuery dataset without requiring a gateway (this is a new feature which will be added into your architecture).

If you can move the Excel data to SharePoint or another cloud storage this could better.

Comment: Nice one. If I connect to 2 live datasets then it won't allow me to make a relationship between them?

Comment: One of the limitations ,you can't establish relationships between tables sourced from different DirectQuery sources